# Get first document returning nothing in Lotus

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

when I'm trying to access a field of the selected document in the current view, I get nothing..
My code:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
  Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim uiview As NotesUIView 
  Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection 
  Dim doc As NotesDocument 
  Dim receive As String 
  Set uiview=ws.CurrentView
  Set dc=uiview.Documents
  Set doc=dc.GetFirstDocument
  If doc Is Not Nothing Then
    receive=doc.GetItemValue("Field name")
  End If
End Sub
```

It never enters the if because doc is always nothing.. and when i remove the if, the error appears when getitemvalue tries to fetch something but it can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dc.GetFirstDocument` returns nothing because the collection is empty. That happens if you don't have select documents with a check mark. `uiview.Documents` delivers only those selected documents and *not* the highlighted document.

If you only want to get the highlighted document in view (the document which is framed) 
[image]
then this will work:

```vb
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set doc = session.DocumentContext
    If Not doc Is Nothing Then
        receive=doc.GetItemValue("FieldName")(0)
        Print receive
    End If
End Sub
```

`session.DocumentContext` returns the highlighted document in view.

If you want to get all selected documents in view

[image]you can use your slightly modified code

```vb
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uiview As NotesUIView
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set uiview = ws.CurrentView
    Set dc = uiview.Documents
    Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        Print doc.GetItemValue ("FieldName")(0)
        Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument (doc)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the key being 'UnprocessedDocuments') :

```
Sub Click (Source as Button)
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim DocColl As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set DocColl = db.UnprocessedDocuments
    Set doc = DocColl.GetFirstDocument()
    if not (doc is Nothing) then
        Print doc.GetItemvalue("FieldName")(0)
    End if
End Sub
```

The currently selected (either highlighted or ticked) documents will populate the document collection.

Cheers.